# How to make string or char constants with macro expansion using ## operator

Tags: c, macros, token, c-preprocessor, stringification

I am trying to do the following:

```
#define mkstr(str) #str
#define cat(x,y) mkstr(x ## y)

int main()
{

   puts(cat(\,n));
   puts(cat(\,t))
   return 0;
}
```

both of the `puts` statements cause error. As `\n` and `n` both are preprocessor tokens I expected output them correctly in those `puts` statements, but Bloodshed/DevC++ compiler giving me the following error:

> 24:1 G:\BIN\cLang\macro2.cpp pasting "\" and "n" does not give a valid preprocessing token

Where is the fact I'm missing?

Comment: Why should `/` and  `n` give `\n`?

Comment: The dev-c++ compiler is **ancient**. Worse than IE6. Don't use it. Get an up-to-date GCC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The preprocessor uses a tokenizer which will require C-ish input. So even when stringifying you cannot pass random garbage to a macro. ==> Don't make your preprocessor sad - it will eat kittens if you do so too often.

Actually, there is no way to create `"\n"` via compile-time concatenation since `"\\" "n"` is a string consisting of the two literals, i.e. "\n".